# Link tap color for TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattributedlabel

I am using a TTTAttributedLabel in my project. I have managed to change the default color and underlining for any link that I create by modifying the link attributes.

```
NSArray *pKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                      (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                     , nil];

NSArray *pObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:pAlertColor,[NSNumber numberWithInt:
                                                                             kCTUnderlineStyleNone], nil];

NSDictionary *pLinkAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:pObjects
                                                                  forKeys:pKeys];

self.alertMessage.linkAttributes = pLinkAttributes;
self.alertMessage.activeLinkAttributes = pLinkAttributes;
```

However, I have noticed that when I tap on the link, it turns red momentarily as any other link does when tapped. I need to change this color. Any clues to how that might be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will like to look at [TTTAttributedLabel documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TTTAttributedLabel/1.13.1/Classes/TTTAttributedLabel.html#//api/name/activeLinkAttributes), specifically at activeLinkAttributes

> activeLinkAttributes
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *activeLinkAttributes
>   Discussion
>
> A dictionary containing the NSAttributedString attributes to be
>   applied to links when they are in the active state. If nil or an empty
>   NSDictionary, active links will not be styled. The default active link
>   style is red and underlined.
>
> Declared In
>
> TTTAttributedLabel.h

Comment: Thanks guys.. I set the same link attributes for activeLinkAttributes as well and it worked. (Basically I did not want the link color to change on tap). I had seen the activeLinkAttributes but did not know that would help me out.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 2 Solution:**

[image]

Specifically, need to set `activeLinkAttributes`, see below example:

```
private func subscriptionNoticeWithDelegate(delegate:TTTAttributedLabelDelegate) -> TTTAttributedLabel {
  let subscriptionNotice:String = "To turn on all notifications, subscribe to our monthly " +
    "service ($0.99/month). If you have already subscribed, please restore your purchase."

  let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
  paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.2

  let subscriptionNoticeAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string:subscriptionNotice, attributes: [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size:15)!,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor().CGColor,
  ])
  let subscriptionNoticeLinkAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(),
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(bool:true),
  ]
  let subscriptionNoticeActiveLinkAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.80),
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(bool:true),
  ]

  let subscriptionNoticeLabel:TTTAttributedLabel = TTTAttributedLabel(frame:CGRectZero)
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.delegate = delegate
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.textInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:10, left:15, bottom:0, right:15)
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.setText(subscriptionNoticeAttributedString) 
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.linkAttributes = subscriptionNoticeLinkAttributes
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.activeLinkAttributes = subscriptionNoticeActiveLinkAttributes

  let subscribeLinkRange = (subscriptionNotice as NSString).rangeOfString("subscribe")
  let subscribeURL = NSURL(string:kSubscriptionNoticeSubscribeURL)!
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.addLinkToURL(subscribeURL, withRange:subscribeLinkRange)

  let restoreLinkRange = (subscriptionNotice as NSString).rangeOfString("restore")
  let restoreURL = NSURL(string:kSubscriptionNoticeRestoreURL)!
  subscriptionNoticeLabel.addLinkToURL(restoreURL, withRange:restoreLinkRange)

  return subscriptionNoticeLabel
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should do something like this

```
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableActiveLinkAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mutableActiveLinkAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
    [mutableActiveLinkAttributes setObject:[UIColor greenColor] forKey:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];   
    label.activeLinkAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableActiveLinkAttributes];
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 4:**

```
let activeLinkAttributes = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: attributedLabel.activeLinkAttributes)
activeLinkAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] = UIColor.blue
attributedLabel.activeLinkAttributes = activeLinkAttributes as NSDictionary as! [AnyHashable: Any]
```

**For Swift 3:**

```
let activeLinkAttributes = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: attributedLabel.activeLinkAttributes)
activeLinkAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.blue
attributedLabel.activeLinkAttributes = activeLinkAttributes as NSDictionary as! [AnyHashable: Any]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Full code to set TTTAttributedLabel in Objective-C**

```
#import "TTTAttributedLabel.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TTTAttributedLabel *attributedLable;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup {
    _attributedLable.numberOfLines = 0;

    NSString *strTC = @"Terms and Condition";
    NSString *strPP = @"Privacy Policy";

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By click continue I agree to %@ and %@.",strTC,strPP];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc];
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.2;

    NSAttributedString *fullAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{
                                                                                                              NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:IZFontNameLatoRegular size:15.0],
                                                                                                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle
                                                                                                              }];
    [_attributedLable setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [_attributedLable setAttributedText:fullAttributedString];

    NSRange rangeTC = [string rangeOfString:strTC];
    NSRange rangePP = [string rangeOfString:strPP];

    NSDictionary *ppActiveLinkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};
    NSDictionary *ppLinkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};

    _attributedLable.activeLinkAttributes = ppActiveLinkAttributes;
    _attributedLable.linkAttributes = ppLinkAttributes;

    NSURL *urlTC = [NSURL URLWithString:@"action://TC"];
    NSURL *urlPP = [NSURL URLWithString:@"action://PP"];

    [_attributedLable addLinkToURL:urlTC withRange:rangeTC];
    [_attributedLable addLinkToURL:urlPP withRange:rangePP];

    _attributedLable.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _attributedLable.delegate = self;
}

//Delegate Method
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"action://TC"]) {
        NSLog(@"terms and conditions click");
    }
    else if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"action://PP"]){
        NSLog(@"privacy policy click");
    }
}
```

**Note : Install Pod file : pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'**

Comment: This is helpful to see it in Objective-C.  One thing to change in this example: `@bug Setting 'attributedText' directly is not recommended, as it may cause a crash when attempting to access any links previously set. Instead, call 'setText:', passing an 'NSAttributedString'.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute "activeLinkAttributes"

```
NSMutableDictionary* attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.attributedLabel.activeLinkAttributes];
[attributes setObject:(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor forKey:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];
self.attributedLabel.activeLinkAttributes = attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

###### For reference, Not changing link color when tapping.

Just disable active link color by code below.

```
self.tttAttributedLabel.inactiveLinkAttributes = nil;
```